# Django REST Swagger with OAuth2 authentication

Tags: django, rest, swagger-2.0

I have a REST API created with Django rest framework. To authenticate my API calls I am using OAuth2 tokens. My question is how can I enable standard username/password authentication in docs generated by Django rest swagger.
Right now i am gettings
`401 : {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."} http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/?format=openapi`

settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Don't perform any authentication on API calls so we don't have any CSRF problems
    # :PRODUCTION: Put back authentication for production version when not testing on same server?
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1000,  # Max number of results returned from a list API call
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    # Use JSONRender so the Web API interface is not shown. This is needed when testing the app on the same server
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'veeu': {
            'type': 'oauth2',
            'flow': 'password',
            'tokenUrl': 'http://localhost:8000/auth/token/',
            'scopes': {
                'write:all': 'Write all',
                'read:all': 'Read all',
            }
        }
    },
}

LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/admin/'
```

When I click Django login it takes me to admin login page. And after I log in, this message is still the same. If I add header `Authorization: Bearer TokenHere` it works. However, the point is to enable username/password login.

Answer (score 0):

To access Swagger documentation, you need SessionAuth with the following in the **settings.py** :

```
# API VERSIONING
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
}
```

This allows you to access Swagger generated documentation. Problem is, whatever endpoint you have protected with **OAuth2** won't be visible via Swagger, at least if you are generating OAuth via "application". The following code does not work at all and I'm linking the thread discussed asking for anyone to work on that feature:

```
# TODO Swagger implementation is not working for password since
# it sends client_id and client_secret as query strings and not as
# user separated with "::"
# The "application" flow setting also that does work
#
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS': [],  # Due to bug described above
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        "customers_auth": {
            "type": "oauth2",
            "tokenUrl": "/o/token/",
            "flow": "password",
            "scopes": {
                "read": "Read scope",
                "write": "Write scope"
            }
        }
    },
}
```